# Save hive table after performing simple HQL on different hive cluster without export+distcp+import

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-hive

I have a **table A** in cluster X.

I want to perform some HQL (*say* `select * from A where A.country = 'INDIA'`) & save output in table B in cluster Y.

I can perform HQL on **table A** & store data in **table temp**. Then, export this hive table to  **table B** in cluster Y using:

```
EXPORT TABLE temp TO 'path/to/hdfs_clusterX';

hadoop distcp hdfs:///path/to/hdfs_clusterX hdfs:///path/to/hdfs_clusterY

IMPORT TABLE Y FROM 'path/to/another/hdfs
```

Is there any other better way rather than creating this **table temp**?

Answer (score 0):

select * from A where A.country = 'INDIA';

Insert the above select result into some other table and then export that to some location on your cluster by using below command :
Let suppose table name is test

export table test to '/path';

After that use distcp command to move that to another cluster

hadoop distcp  source path destination path ;

Comment: You could improve your answer by formatting it. It is not clear at the first glance, what is a command and what is a parameter and what is a parameter description.